# How to push code again when Git Revert is used

Tags: git, github

Pushed My Code From Branch A to Branch Development
Now for some reason realised the code doesn't need to go so reverted the branch a code from development
Command used git revert

After Making Changes in Branch A, when i tries to push to Branch Development i am not able to merge all the files it says already merged.

What can be done in this case.

Comment: You push commits; revert makes a new commit; so you push a revert just like you push any other commit. Your problem likely has nothing to do with `git push`: you just don't like the fact that you reverted a *merge*. If that's the case, see the existing questions and answers about reverting a reverted merge.

Answer (score 0):

You can `git cherry-pick` the new commit(s). Let's say you have merged the following commits a and b from Branch A into Branch Development:

Branch Development: a - b

By reverting them you have appended 2 new 'revert' commits c and d to Branch Development that inverted the changes introduced by a and b:

Branch Development: a - b - c  - d

Now when you try to merge commits a and newly created commit e (assuming b was discarded) from Branch A, Git says a is already merged into Branch Development which is the case as a already exists in history. You can however run on the Branch Development:

```
git cherry-pick e
```

e being the commit hash. The e commit will be picked from Branch A and applied to the Development branch.